# how to properly build tilix?

Tags: linux, gcc, d, ldc

I decided to build tilix by cloning the code from the [repository](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix).

I understand that the compiler must be LDC, but I don’t know what exactly to change.

`dub build --build release`

But I stumbled upon the current issue:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib7adler32FkAxvZk: error: undefined reference to 'adler32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib5crc32FkAxvZk: error: undefined reference to 'crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8compressFAxviZAh: error: undefined reference to 'compress2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib10uncompressFAxvmiZAv: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib10uncompressFAxvmiZAv: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib10uncompressFAxvmiZAv: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8Compress5errorMFiZv: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8Compress6__dtorMFZv: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8Compress8compressMFAxvZQe: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8Compress5flushMFiZAv: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8Compress5flushMFiZAv: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib8Compress5flushMFiZAv: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib10UnCompress5errorMFiZv: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib10UnCompress6__dtorMFZv: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function _D3std4zlib10UnCompress10uncompressMFAxvZQe: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function deflateInit: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function inflateInit: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function deflateInit2: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit2_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function inflateInit2: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit2_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libphobos2-ldc.a(zlib.o):function inflateBackInit: error: undefined reference to 'inflateBackInit_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: that looks like it just didn't link in zlib, you might be able to hack it by running `LDLAGS=-lz dub build --build release` maybe

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @DejanLekic, ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

[This forum post](https://forum.dlang.org/post/txcnxqlkcgjtbsjmddgm@forum.dlang.org) suggests that it is related to way Ubuntu packages ldc:

> This sounds like a misconfigured distro-LDC. zlib is usually integrated into libphobos, but distros tend to favor the distro's libz.so and patch it out. That must be handled in /etc/ldc2.conf though, with something like `-defaultlib=phobos2-ldc,z,druntime-ldc` (and possibly a zlib1g-dev package dependency)

Digging around in /etc/ldc2.conf might give you a better idea what went wrong.

Alternatively, dmd comes bundled its own zlib sources (at least on archlinux) that I suppose might be compiled into your executable with importC. It's worth to try, on my machine it works.

```
dub build --build release --compiler=dmd
```